# In Pycharm , Selecting Interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, virtual, environment, interpreter

Let's say that Python has virtual environments env1, env2.

When working with files within env1, I select the env1 interpreter, and when working with env2, I repeat the task of switching to the env2 interpreter.

Can't I skip this course? Because this is too cumbersome.

When I open a file in virtual environment env1, I want the env1 interpreter to be automatically selected, and when I open a file in virtual environment env2, I hope the interpreter change itself without selecting a separate setting menu.

I'm using Pycharm. If possible, I want to know the function in Pycharm, and if it's not right, it's okay to do it in VS code.

Comment: What is the reason to use two environments? You can put the files in separate projects (as far as I know, you can only specify one venv per project). But you can still work with them in the same window. (Alternatively you can open a subprocess, but thats very likely not what you want)

Comment: @bitflip    Oh, I understood. I can do the project differently. Thanks